# Function does not work on first render instead the series is generated after the subsequent renders

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

My function generateSeriesDataWithColor() seems like it does not load before the component or page renders.

So, the seriesWithColor should get the data genrated by generateSeriesDataWithColor() right away when the component is loaded but it does not get generated at the first render, instead if the component is rendered again, the colors and the graph shows up.

```
    import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
    import Highcharts from "highcharts";
    import './SkillsGraph.scss';
    import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
    import HeadingMain from "../../Heading/HeadingMain/HeadingMain";

    export default function SkillsGraph(){

    const skills = ['HTML5/CSS3/JS', 'Java11', 'PHP', 'MySql', 'MongoDB', 'ReactJS', 'ExpressJS'];
    const series = {
        name: 'Skill Level', 
        data: [ 10, 9.5, 7, 9.5, 8, 8.5, 8]
    };

    const seriesWithColor = generateSeriesDataWithColor(series); // This is where the series is assigned to the var
    
    // Randomly generate colors 
    function generateRandomColor(){
        let maxVal = 0xFFFFFF; // 16777215
        let randomNumber = Math.random() * maxVal; 
        randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);
        randomNumber = randomNumber.toString(16);
        let randColor = randomNumber.padStart(6, 0);   
        return `#${randColor.toUpperCase()}`
    }

    // Generate the data with random conlor
    function generateSeriesDataWithColor(seriesData){

        const data = seriesData.data;

        const dataArray = data.map((item) => {
            let color = generateRandomColor();
            while(color === "#FFFFFF"){
                color = generateRandomColor();
            }

            let dataObj = {
                y: item,
                color: color
            }

            return dataObj;
        })


        let seriesWithColor = {
            name: 'Skill Level',
            data: dataArray
        }
    
        return seriesWithColor; //This is from where the data/series is returned
    }

    // Options for the graph
    let options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 400
        },
        title: {
            align: 'left',
            text: 'Skills represented'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: skills,
            visible: true,
            type: 'Skills categorised',
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            title: {
                text: 'Skill Level',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            column: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
        colors: [
            '#ff0000',
            '#00ff00',
            '#0000ff',
            '#0000ff',
            '#0000ff',
            '#0000ff',
            '#0000ff'
        ],
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: seriesWithColor // This is where the generated data/series is used
    } 

    return (
        <Row>
            <Col md={3}>
                <HeadingMain name="This is Legend"></HeadingMain>
            </Col>
            <Col md={9}>
                <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} className="chart"></HighchartsReact>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I tried using useEffect hook to complete the wanted task but it gives an error message - 'React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'generateSeriesDataWithColor' and 'series'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps'. (Please check the code below)

```
const [seriesWithColor, setSeries] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    generateSeriesDataWithColor(series)
    .then(data => setSeries(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

Comment: Off Topic: `generateRandomColor = () => "#" + (Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0x1000000).toString(16).slice(1).toUpperCase();` your current code can never generate `#FFFFFF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Series needs to be an array of objects instead of a single object:

```
  let options = {
    ...,
    series: [seriesWithColor] // This is where the generated data/series is used
  };
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-h4r493?file=/demo.jsx

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series

Comment: Cool, that worked, thanks. But can you explain it a little more? Like if series needs to an array of objects, how does it work on the second render? I mean it should not work at all with a single object, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Hi @Anurag Rawal, What do you exactly mean? Series must be an array, as specified in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series If it comes to rerenders, the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper uses `chart.update`: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update to apply changes in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the function within useEffect hook to make sure that the data is available.

Comment: Yes, I did try that but it gave me an error, so I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong. Can you check the code above that I mentioned in the recent edit?

Comment: You should include in the squared brackets seriesWithColor, in order to catch the moment the data is available.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well. It does not work and gives the same error

Comment: Try this link, it will give you a clue - https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect